# Jasmine test for Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jasmine

How to test (using Jasmine) if the pre defined function such compute or subscribe are called when the observable variables change in knockoutJs

For Example:

```
self.report.subscribe(function(){
    clearAll();
});
```

If i change the value of report observable the clearAll function is called but the subscribe function is not executing as expected

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spyOn method.
syntax:

```
spyOn(myObject, 'nameOfMethodToSpyOn');
//do stuff
expect(moObject.nameOfTheMethodToSpyOn).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

example:

```
spyOn(window, 'alert');
alert('hi');
expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hi');
```

so you could do something like:

```
spyOn(myModel, 'clearAll');
myModel.report('something');
expect(myModel.clearAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

reference: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

You should only test your own code. The subscribe function is part of KnockoutJS and doesn't need any more testing.

Comment: Thankyou for your look at this. I tried the spyOn but still the change in observable is not triggering the subscribe. I even tried a console log within the subscribe its not been called. Where do you think i am going wrong ? @Yoeri

Comment: "If i change the value of report observable the clearAll function is called". Then what is not triggering?

Can you provide a full example using plnkr.co ?

Comment: The problem was with Ko mapping and its working fine now

Comment: It seems like you asked a question unrelated to your problem. You asked how you should test something using Jasmine, so I provided an answer accordingly.